# How to get an element from a JSON object based on their position in the object?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, pug

I have an object in my mongodb database:

```
{ _id: 5490dcbacc08e6c1c37752b1,

    Java: { posts: [] },

    Idde: { posts: [] },

    Node: { posts: [] } 

}
```

I want to access the second object, third, and fourth.
Say I want to fetch them in my js code and send them to Jade to display them.

So my route file has this:

```
db.categories.find({}, function(err,category ){
        if(err)
        {
            console.error(err);
        }
    else{
        // My code should be here and create an object 
        res.render('follow', {title: 'Follow post', categories:**Here I should insert the category object**});
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no order in object keys, so "third element of object" is meaningless.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Then how do I access Java, Idde, and Node arrays?

Comment: What should be in '**Here I should insert the category object**'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `.find` returns a collection.  To get a single category, you need to use `.findOne`, or iterate through collection that `.find` returns.

Second, this is not a "JSON object", this is just an object, which you can access using normal dot notation: `category.Java`, `category.Node` etc.